# how to make t-student test in loop in r?

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I'm new in R  and what I want to do is something very simple but I need help.

[image: img]

I have a database that looks like the one above; where spot number = "name" of a protein, grupo = group I and II and APF = fluorescent reading.
I want to do a tstudent test to each protein, by comparing groups I and II, but in a loop.

In the database above there only 1 protein (147) but im my real database i have 444 proteins.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Considering your data is in a data frame called `gel`, this should work: `lapply(split(gel, gel$Spot.number), function(spot) t.test(APF ~ grupo, spot))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with some fake data:

```
set.seed(0)
Spot.number <- rep(147:149, each=10)
grupo <- rep(rep(1:2, each=5), 3)
APF <- rnorm(30)
gel <- data.frame(Spot.number, grupo, APF)

> head(gel)
  Spot.number grupo        APF
1         147     1  2.1780699
2         147     1 -0.2609347
3         147     1 -1.6125236
4         147     1  1.7863384
5         147     1  2.0325473
6         147     2  0.6261739
```

You can use `lapply` to loop through the subsets of `gel`, split by the `Spot.number`:

```
tests <- lapply(split(gel, gel$Spot.number), function(spot) t.test(APF ~ grupo, spot))
```

or just

```
tests <- by(gel, gel$Spot.number, function(spot) t.test(APF ~ grupo, spot))
```

You can then move on to e.g. taking only the p values:

```
sapply(tests, "[[", "p.value")

#      147       148       149 
#0.2941609 0.9723856 0.5726007
```

or confidence interval

```
sapply(tests, "[[", "conf.int")
#           147       148        149
# [1,] -0.985218 -1.033815 -0.8748502
# [2,]  2.712395  1.066340  1.4240488
```

And the resulting vector or matrix will already have the `Spot.number` as names which can be very helpful.

Comment: MOLX, thanks for your help, but i'm still with the same problem. Every protein has the same p-value!! The database you created is exactly like my database. When copy/past your script everything works fine, but when i use it in my database, every protein has the same p-value. So something is wrong with the "construction" of my database.....

Comment: MOLX, i was doing something wrong with my database....i fix it and now everything fine and as it should be! thank you ...life saver..

Comment: @InêsDiniz Just a quick note: Your name and code suggest you are a native portuguese speaker. If that's true, check [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) some time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a t.test within each group using [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and my [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package. If your data is stored in a data frame called `dat`, you would do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

results <- dat %>%
    group_by(Spot.number) %>%
    do(tidy(t.test(APF ~ grupo, .)))
```

This works by performing `t.test(APF ~ grupo, .)` on each group defined by `Spot.number`. The `tidy` function from broom then turns it into a one-row data frame so that it can be recombined. The `results` data frame will then contain one row per protein (`Spot.number`) with columns including `estimate`, `statistic`, and `p.value`.

See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) for more on the combination of dplyr and broom.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, for all the protein, (i have tried 6 to start with, i get the same estimated (1,2) statistic, p-value, and so on...So something may be missing!?

Comment: should i give the data for one more protein to test it?

Comment: @InêsDiniz can you edit the result of `dput(head(dat, 100))` into your answer? That will create a reproducible example

Comment: David Robinson, i was doing something wrong with my database....i fix it and now everything fine and as it should be! thank you  also